# Android Cardboard: Unity or Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I'm a brand new in Android VR, and I would like to ask for your advice. So I've just got to this link: https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/
because I would like to start developing Android VR. My question is: Shall I use and learn the Android SDK or shall I use the Unity for developing Android VR ? 
What are the advantages and drawbacks for choosing one, instead of the other?

Are there any restrictions, what I can't do with the one , but yes with the another ?

I'm looking forward to hear your experience!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to achieve.
I developed applications with both plattforms.

The Android SDK is rather poor when you want to develop a real 3D-application.

Unity:

- Enables complex 3D-animations and physics
- Easy import of your own 3D-content
- Enables porting for other platforms (iOS, windows app)

Android SDK:

- May be better if VR is just a small part of your application.

Comment: hey Mike76, thanks for getting back to me. I would like to create an app for Android, if you see a place in the office, we can write to the screen, who sitting there, what is the email of her/his and so on. So as you walking around the office, you can gate the details of the colleagues by their sitting place. So, what do you suggest, my friend ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want great 3D performance and easy 3D Scenes building, I would suggest go for Unity, I have found it very easy to use, starting from the "DemoScene" published on git:

https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-java/

I did not choose to go for the Android SDK , since I found it involved OpenGL programming, which to me seems a lot harder.
Other than that I do not know the nature of your app, so It's hard to know how well programming in Unity will be convenient for you.